# Unreal Conditional and Subjunctive

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

I have read that in using unreal conditionals, irrespective of personal pronouns, it mandatory to use subjunctives to form verbs.

" If Jack **was** playing they would probably win " - if I am correct, the verb '**was**' should be replaced by the subjunctive '**were**'.

I have taken the above sentence from a famous [English Learning Website](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-time-clauses-and-if-clauses). Please let me why this sentence is correct ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! That's true, you should use *were* in that sentence. But many people sin against this rule, native speakers too, so there's your explanation.